# Fetch a nested element from HTML using python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
<div class="product ">
<div class="information">
    <h4 class="name ">Biryani</h4>
        <p class="description ">mutton mix biryani</p>
        </div>

    <div class="details">
        <div class="orderDetail">
            <p class="price ">&#163;12.95</p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

For each class **product** I want to fetch the text of class **name and price.**

The expected output is :

**name : Biryani, 
price : 12.95**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.selector import Selector

doc = """
<div class="product ">
  <div class="information">
    <h4 class="name ">Biryani</h4>
    <p class="description ">mutton mix biryani</p>
  </div>

  <div class="details">
    <div class="orderDetail">
      <p class="price ">&#163;12.95</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
"""

sel = Selector(text=doc, type="html")

sel_products = sel.xpath('//div[@class="product "]')

for product in sel_products:
    name = product.xpath('.//h4[@class="name "]/text()').extract_first()
    price = product.xpath('.//p[@class="price "]/text()').extract_first()
    print "name: " + name + ", price: " + price  # name: Biryani, price: £12.95
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://localhost:8000/data.html']

    def parse(self, response):
                products = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'product ')]")  

                for product in products:
                    _name = product.xpath(".//h4[starts-with(@class, 'name ')]").extract_first()

                    _price = product.xpath(".//p[starts-with(@class, 'price')]").extract_first()

                    print (_name, _price, counter)
```